# How to convert a spark dataframe schema to an avro schema using pyspark

Tags: pyspark, spark-avro

Is there a `pyspark` function which could convert below `_schema` variable to an `avro schema?

```py
df_schema = spark.read.format('parquet').load(input_directory)
_schema = df_schema.schema
```